# `Delete` key doesn't work on vim insert mode for deleting previously typed content

Tags: vim

I opened vim in my `iterm2`. Firstly, I typed something on insert mode, like

```
Hello
```

At this stage, if I didn't exit from insert mode, `delete` key works and can delete the whole word if I want.

If I quit insert mode, and open insert mode again, this `Hello` can't be removed by `delete` key. But the newly typed-in content can be removed.

I've renamed my .vimrc, problem still exits.

In the shell command-line, my `delete` key works well.

And I did some test on remote server through iterm, didn't encounter the same issue.

What could be the cause of this problem? How to fix it?

PS: As I'm using macbook, the `delete` key is corresponding for  `backspace` in PC.

Answer (score 5):

Try this snippet

```
" Allow backspacing everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```